# codename one some coding questions

Tags: codenameone

1. If I am creating forms WITHOUT using the designer, exactly how to I attach an action to a button event...

   ```
   Button btnRegister = new Button();
   btnRegister.setName("btnRegister");
   btnRegister.setText("Register");
   f.addComponent(btnRegister);
   ```

I want to be able to show another form (used command in designer, not sure how to do that in code) as well as perform some other actions (ie: send request to a web service - I presume this is handled through the ActionListener).

1. When I am creating labels it says label.setAligment has been deprecated and to use style.alignment instead...

How would I center the following label...

```
Label lblRestName = new Label();
lblRestName.setName("lblRestName");
lblRestName.setText("Name");    // TODO : center this text
f.addComponent(lblRestName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a listener to your button.

```
         btnRegister.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){

          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ){
           Form f = new Form();
           ...
           f.show();
          }
        });
```

Regarding you 2nd question you can change the alignment using the designer theme entries add "Label" entry and change it's alignment to center in the tool.
In code you can do the following:

```
 lblRestName.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
```

Make sure your form layout is not flowlayout use box layout y to see the effect.